# SWT-How to transfer data from One Page to another

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a WizardPage called PageOne with a text box, I want to print the data entered in the textBox of PageOne to be displayed in Page two.

I have tried saving the value in another object and passing that object to PageTwo object and they try displaying, I have tried sending pageOne object itself. But in both the case it prints out NULL. I believe it is printing out the default value i.e null is loaded while loading the page.

How do I handle such scenarios?

Code:

PageOne:

```java
 public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        label1.setText("Put a value here.");

        text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        text1.setText("");
        text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    setPageComplete(true);
                }
            }
        });
        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        text1.setLayoutData(gd);
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(true);
    }
```

PageTwo:

```java
public class PageTwo extends WizardPage {
    private Text text1;
    private Composite container;
    private Text text2;
    PageOne pageOne;

    public PageTwo(PageOne pageOne) {
        super("PageTwo ");
        this.pageOne=pageOne;
        setTitle("PageTwo ");
        setDescription("Fake Wizard: PageTwo");
    }

    public void setText(Text text){
        this.text2=text;
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        String result="";

        if(pageOne.getText()!=null){
            result=pageOne.getText().toString();
        }

        label1.setText("Put a value here."+result);

       /* text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        text1.setText("");
        text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    setPageComplete(true);
                }
            }
        });
        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        text1.setLayoutData(gd);*/
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(true);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1.getText();
    }
}
```

**Update**

Changes made:

In Wizard Page:

```java
public void addPages() {
    super.addPages(); 
    DataTransferObject dto = new DataTransferObject();
    addPage(new PageOne(dto));
    addPage(new PageTwo(dto));
    addPage(new PageThree());
}
```

DataTransferObject

```java
public class DataTransferObject {

    String data=null;

    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setData(String data){
        this.data=data;
    }

}
```

PageOne:

```java
public class PageOne extends WizardPage {
    private Text text1;
    private Composite container;
    private DataTransferObject dto;

    public Text getText(){
        return this.text1;
    }

    public PageOne(DataTransferObject dto) {
        super("PageOne ");
        setTitle("PageOne ");
        this.dto=dto;
        setDescription("Fake Wizard: PageOne");
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;
        Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        label1.setText("Put a value here.");

        text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
        text1.setText("");
        text1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (!text1.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    setPageComplete(true);
                }
            }
        });
        GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        text1.setLayoutData(gd);
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(true);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Data is "+this.text1.getText().toString());
        dto.setData(this.text1.getText().toString());
        return super.getNextPage();
    }
}
```

PageTwo:

```java
public class PageTwo extends WizardPage {
    private Text text1;
    private Composite container;
    private Text text2;
    PageOne pageOne;
    DataTransferObject dto; 

    public PageTwo(DataTransferObject dto) {
        super("PageTwo ");
        this.dto=dto;
        setTitle("PageTwo ");
        setDescription("Fake Wizard: PageTwo");
    }

    public void setText(Text text){
        this.text2=text;
    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(layout);
        layout.numColumns = 2;
       // Label label1 = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
        String result="";

        org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List single = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        if(!(dto.data==null)){
            single.add(dto.getData());
        }
        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(true);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1.getText();
    }
}
```

UI Part:

PageOne
[image]

Page Two

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to pass the same object to both pages when you construct them.

So your `Wizard` might do:

```java
@Override
public void addPages()
{
  DataTransferObject dto = new DataTransferObject();

  addPage(new PageOne(dto));

  addPage(new PageTwo(dto);
}
```

And the wizard pages would look like:

```java
public class PageOne extends WizardPage {
    DataTransferObject dto;

    public PageOne(DataTransferObject dto) {
        super("PageOne");

        this.dto = dto;
    }
```

```java
public class PageTwo extends WizardPage {
    DataTransferObject dto;

    public PageTwo(DataTransferObject dto) {
        super("PageTwo ");

        this.dto = dto;
    }
```

`DataTransferObject` is some class that you write containing the data you want to share. `PageOne` should set values in to the object so that `PageTwo` can retrieve them.

`PageTwo` should wait for the `setVisible` call to access the data:

```java
 @Override
 public void setVisible(final boolean visible)
 {
   if (visible)
    {
      // TODO access data and update the controls which show the data
    }
 }

super.setVisible(visible);
```

}

The `setVisible` code must update the controls which have already been created. So for a `Text` control you would call `setText` and so on.

Comment: I have tried implementing your suggestion but, Its still giving me an empty string in Page Two. I am unable to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: There should be no problem with this, show us your code.

Comment: I have updated it in the Question please have a look at it.

Comment: On Clicking the next button, I could observe that the entered values are shown in the console due to System.out.println("Data is "+this.text1.getText().toString()); in nextPage method of PageOne.

Comment: you can't access the data in `createControl`  - that is called when the pages are created. Use `setVisible` - see updated answer.

Comment: Greg, Sorry to keep coming back to you again and again. In setVisible method of PageTwo has the below code. 

**this.result=dto.getData();
  super.setVisible(visible);**

But it still gives me the same result. I tried placing a debug point in create control method. it hits only once i.e then the plugin is getting loaded. On reaching the setVisible the code it assigns the value but there the value is not getting updated in the display. do I need to call createControl explicitly?

Comment: No you must **never** call createControl yourself, it has already been called and cannot be called again. You must update the control you want to show the data in. So for a `Text` control call `setText` or for a `List` call `add`